# Why does my Tkinter login button not work in my program?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is a simple login screen. I don't know what is wrong with it. When I click login nothing happens. Please advise.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

window = Tk()
window.title("PyOS")
window.geometry('1000x500')


user = Label(window,text="Username")
pass1 = Label(window,text="Password")
login = Button(window,text="Login")
def clicked(login):
    wrong = Label(window,text="Wrong Password")
    wrong.grid(column=1,row=2)
userentry = Entry(window,font="Sanserif",width=30)
passentry = Entry(window,font="Marlett",show="n",width=17)
userentry.grid(column=1, row=0)
passentry.grid(column=1, row=1)
user.grid(column=0, row=0)
pass1.grid(column=0, row=1)
login.grid(column=0, row=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the button which function to execute when it is pressed. This is done by using the `command` parameter of Button.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

window = Tk()
window.title("PyOS")

def clicked():
    wrong = Label(window,text="Wrong Password")
    wrong.grid(column=1,row=2)

user = Label(window,text="Username")
pass1 = Label(window,text="Password")
login = Button(window,text="Login", command=clicked)

userentry = Entry(window,font="Sanserif")
passentry = Entry(window,font="Marlett", show="*")
userentry.grid(column=1, row=0)
passentry.grid(column=1, row=1)
user.grid(column=0, row=0)
pass1.grid(column=0, row=1)
login.grid(column=0, row=2)

window.mainloop()
```

[image]